# Module level method and a Class within same module in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, module

I have the similar module in my Rails application

```
module Demo
 def self.create 
  puts 'inside module method'
  AnotherTestClass.new('testing')
 end
 class ModuleClass
  def initialize(test)
    @test = test
    puts "inside class #{@test}"
  end
 end
end

module Demo
 class AnotherTestClass < ModuleClass 
 end
end
```

So when I call Demo.create in my Controller, I am getting the following error

> undefined method `create' for Demo:Module

Note: When I execute this code in irb, it works.

Comment: Try renaming your module something other than Test. I bet it's getting messed up with Test unit.

Comment: @rainkinz - I have a different name, I am not posting the same module name has i have it in my application due to obvious reasons.

Comment: @rajkumarts You don't have to put the actual name here, just something other than `Test`.

Comment: ok i have changed the Test to Demo

Comment: `Demo.create` should be defined here as you have it.

Comment: @tadman - i don't get it .. what do you mean by defined here ??

Comment: Looking at the error, it seems that your module `Test`/ `Demo` is accessible to controller but `create` method is not defined for the module.  Just verify the method name is not mis-spelled in your module, check if it is `create`.

Comment: I think you should post the code or a snippet of the code you're having trouble with as this seems to work as written.

Comment: @KirtiThorat - nope, they are not mis-spelled.

Comment: @rainkinz - this code is pretty close to what i have in my actual application ..

Comment: If I paste that code in and type `Demo.create` it works, so obviously something's different on your end.